# Proxy settings in RStudio for third party API access

Tags: api, proxy, rstudio, http-proxy, adobe-analytics

I'm using RStudio on a server that is behind my company's firewall. I referred to the link [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200488488-Configuring-R-to-Use-an-HTTP-Proxy) and did the same changes in my RProfile script:

RProfile

```
http_proxy=http://proxy.dom.com:80
http_proxy_user=user:passwd
```

I'm trying to access an API (Omniture a.k.a. api.omniture.com) using the package [RSiteCatalyst](https://github.com/randyzwitch/RSiteCatalyst) and even though I mentioned the proxy, I'm unable to bypass the firewall. Below is what I do:

```
library(RSiteCatalyst)
SCAuth('username','shared-secret') # Authentication
```

And the error that I get

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
Could not resolve host: api.omniture.com
```

Before going to IT I came here for the StackOverflow gods to help out. Would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that article has a typo. Can you put the `http_proxy` lines in your `.Renviron` rather than your `.Rprofile`, then restart RStudio? (If that does the job, we'll update the article!)

Comment: I tried the same but still failing. I added the http_proxy & http_proxy_user lines inside .Renviron, but still get the same error. Can you tell what's going wrong ?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, as per your suggestion, now my .Renviron file has the http_proxy & http_proxy_user lines. RStudio is reading these values when I restart it. However, still not able to bypass the firewall. The proxy address works for other applications like pip and github. So not sure what other issue is causing this behavior. Do you have any suggestions ? Would appreciate it. Thanks!